# PostgreSQL. Как получить базы текущего пользователя?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Как получить БД, к которым пользователь имеет доступ? Или наоборот как узнать по БД, какие пользователи имеют к ней доступ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как получить БД, к которым пользователь имеет доступ? Или наоборот как узнать по БД, какие пользователи имеют к ней доступ?

Для PostgreSQL свойственна собственная методика раздачи прав доступа. Которую можно разделить на два "шага":

- доступ непосредственно к серверу
- доступ к объектам сервера

**Доступ к серверу**

Доступ к серверу осуществляется, помимо конфигов, с помощью механизма "ролей". В узком смысле ([читаем про роли](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/database-roles)) "роль" можно трактовать и как "пользователя". Каждая роль получает или не получает доступ ко всему кластеру баз данных на сервере. Информацию об этом можно получить следующим запросом:

```
SELECT 
  rolname AS "User", -- название ролей
  CASE WHEN rolsuper OR rolcanlogin 
       THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS "Access" -- есть ли право для логина?
FROM 
  pg_roles;
```

Пример:

```
---------------
User  | Access
------+--------
pgsql | Yes
User  | Yes
Testo | No
---------------
```

**Доступ к объектам сервера**

В данном случае будем выбирать объекты типа **"база данных"**, и определять какая "роль" имеет к ним `ACL` с типом `'CONNECT'`. Это можно реализовать следующим запросом:

```
WITH bases AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      datname AS "db",
      (aclexplode(datacl)).grantor AS "grantor",
      (aclexplode(datacl)).grantee AS "grantee",
      (aclexplode(datacl)).privilege_type AS "type"
    FROM 
      pg_database
  ) AS Query
  WHERE 
    Query.type = 'CONNECT'
),
roles AS (
  SELECT * FROM pg_roles
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      bases.db AS db,
      roles1.rolname AS user
    FROM 
      bases
    LEFT JOIN
      roles AS roles1
      ON bases.grantor = roles1.oid
  ) AS one
  UNION
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      bases.db AS db,
      roles2.rolname AS user
    FROM 
      bases
    LEFT JOIN
      roles AS roles2
      ON bases.grantee = roles2.oid
  ) AS two
) AS res
WHERE
  res.user NOTNULL
```

Пример:

```
=========================
db               | user
=================+=======
database_clients | pgsql
template0        | pgsql
template1        | pgsql
testo            | User
testo            | pgsql
testo_final      | User
=================+=======
```